# How to achieve mouseover effect where a hover div slides in from the side

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been taking a look at this WordPress theme: http://themes.thunderbuddies4life.com/?theme=longwave_wp

When a tile is hovered it seems a translucent div slides over the tile from the edge the mouse entered. I think a single div may be used for this but I'm not sure how it's acheived from looking at the page source.

I am pretty good with html and css but my jQuery is quite basic. I know this is a bit open ended but a brief explanation of the techniques involved would be helpful.

---

Edit: Thinking about it, without delving into the page source this is how I think the approach might work:

1. Each tile has it's own translucent overlay child div with title on it etc.
2. Each overlay div is positioned somewhere outside the tile div. The tile has `overflow:hidden`
3. When the mouse hovers the div I use jQuery to work out which side the mouse entered (how?)
4. I then apply a css class to the overlay div: either *top*, *bottom*, *left* or *right*. CSS will kick in to instantly position the overlay div just outside the corresponding edge of the tile div.
5. jQuery then offsets the overlay div with animation to move it into position over the tile.

The tiles will be dynamically sized so jQuery will be needed to redefine the offset amounts depending on the tile size.

Comment: Interesting! well for a start each tile has its own translucent div

Comment: Yes, well as PSCoder suggested it is a good idea to `append()` the div upon hover. However we are then faced with the problem of the div having the correct title, tags etc. The next tricky bit will be getting the div to slide in and out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using this - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

I also started a CSS only version - http://codepen.io/seanjacob/pen/rmIcD

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, I will give it a bash later. Your CSS one looks good but: 1. The overlay does not exit on the same side as the mouse; 2. Can the overlay contain a title?

Comment: Great! I know how I would get the text in but not exiting on the same side of the mouse just using css yet.

Answer (score 0):

first idea: on mouseenter you can begin doing maths to determine the entering edge based on mouse coordinates. Then when you know if the mouse entered from top, right, bottom or left you can perform the necessary animation